# How to get the value of Razor variable in js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In Razor I get a table of IDs from a model sent by the controller. How can I get the table in javascript code?
The variable `@t[i]` is taken from razor code it contains the last value of the counter. I want to take each time the value of the counter of js `j`:

```
$("#buttonGENERER").click(function () {

    @{
        var t = new string[@Model.Count];
        var I = 0;
        foreach (var exam in @Model)
        {
            if (i < @Model.Count)
            { t[i] = @exam.EXAMEN_PRESC_ID; i++; }
        }
       }


    //alert("@t[1]");

    var j=0;
    var I = parseInt("@i");
    var array = [];
    debugger;

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        array[j] = "@t[i]";

    }
});
```

Comment: Delete all that and use `var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` which converts your model to a javascript array.

Comment: hi Stephen in fact i need  @exam.EXAMEN_PRESC_ID because they are  the ids  of my inputs for example @exam.EXAMEN_PRESC_ID=7788       $("#7788").value to get the value of them

Comment: You controller should be calculating that value and putting a plain value on the model. This is putting too much logic into a view.

Comment: i get the values from inputs

Comment: If you just want the `EXAMEN_PRESC_ID` and not all the properties, just change `Model` to `Model.Select(x => x.EXAMEN_PRESC_ID)`, but you really should be doing that filtering in the controller not the view (pass the result as a `ViewBag` property, or better still, use a view model with a property for the collection of `EXAMEN_PRESC_ID`)

Comment: And what do you mean _get the values from inputs_? - nothing in your code gets any values from inputs - just the original model.

Comment: ok i will try it thnks stephen

Comment: You mention several things that are not in your code.  How about a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).